# Multiplicar elementos da primeira matriz por 3 e diminuir elementos da segunda matriz por 3 no Python

Tags: python

Meu código precisa ter **duas matrizes cada uma com 5 elementos e a primeira matriz precisa multiplicar os seus elementos por 3** enquanto que **os elementos da segunda matriz precisam diminuir seus elementos por 3**, mas ele retorna um erro `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'` causado pela linha `mt1, mt2 = (mt1) * 2, (mt2) - 5`, como se resolve isso?

```
Entrada: 
02 03 04 05 06
10 20 30 40 50
```

```
Saída esperada: 
06  7
09  17
12  27
15  37
16  47
```

```
Meu código:

i = 0 # Linha
j = 0 # Coluna

mt1 = input().split() # Matriz 1
mt2 = input().split() # Matriz 2

mt1, mt2 = (mt1) * 2, (mt2) - 5 # PARTE ERRADA DO CÓDIGO

mt3 = zip(mt1, mt2) # Unindo as matrizes em uma com ZIP

for i, j in mt3: # linha e coluna associadas a terceira matriz
    print(i,j) # Exibe linha e coluna
```

Comment: Tradução do errro: `TypeError: tipos de operandos não-suportados para -: 'list' e 'int'`. Ou seja, não se pode subtrair uma lista de um inteiro ou um inteiro de uma lista...
O que você quer fazer é subtrair um inteiro para cada elemento da lista, ou seja, você deve iterar a lista e subtrair a cada item iterado...

Comment: Sim, cada elemento da primeira matriz tem que ser multiplicado por 3 e cada elemento da segunda matriz subtraído por 3.

Comment: Não foi uma pergunta.. eu estava tentando te explicar que você não consegue subtrair um número de uma lista. Você não consegue fazer `lista - 4`, isso não funciona, você deve percorrer esta lista e subtrair `4` de cada item da lista percorrido. Você não está fazendo isso no seu código

Comment: Qual a versão do seu python?

Comment: Spyder (Python 3.6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, não precisa declarar `i` e `j` previamente pra usar naquele `for`.

Em segundo lugar, você precisa converter os elementos de `mt1` e `mt2` para `int`, pois quando você faz o `split` ele gera uma lista de strings. Sem converter para `int` não será possível fazer as operações aritméticas de multiplicação e subtração.

```
mt1 = [int(x) for x in input().split()] # Matriz 1
mt2 = [int(x) for x in input().split()] # Matriz 2
```

Em terceiro lugar, 6*3=18, ou seja, a última linha da saída esperada tem que ser `18 47` e não `16 47`.

Agora podemos partir pra resolução do problema de fato.

> a primeira matriz precisa multiplicar os seus elementos por 3

Dá pra fazer isso já na conversão de string pra `int`.

```
mt1 = [int(x) * 3 for x in input().split()] # Matriz 1
```

> os elementos da segunda matriz precisam diminuir seus elementos por 3

Mesma lógica usada na `mt1`.

```
mt2 = [int(x) - 3 for x in input().split()] # Matriz 2
```

Código completo:

```
mt1 = [int(x) * 3 for x in input().split()]
mt2 = [int(x) - 3 for x in input().split()]

mt3 = zip(mt1, mt2)

for i, j in mt3:
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: Ótima resposta, só para complementar que na versão do python 2.7 se colocado apenas números e sem espaço, por exemplo: 01, ou, 200 o python convertia para int. das versões 3.x todo input é string.

Comment: @JonathandeToni Sim, `input()` no Python 2 é mais ou menos equivalente a fazer `eval(input())` no Python 3. Por isso, no Python 2 a preferência é usar `raw_input()`.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta

Answer (score 1):

Usando `numpy` é possível realizar operações diretamente com arrays e números:

```
import numpy as np

mt1 = input().split() # Matriz 1

mt1 = np.array(mt1, dtype='int') # passa o input para um numpy.array

mt1 = mt1 * 3 # realiza a operação
```

A modificação necessária para o seu código seria:

```
import numpy as np

mt1 = np.array(input().split(), dtype='int') * 3
mt2 = np.array(input().split(), dtype='int') - 3

for i, j in zip(mt1, mt2):
    print(i, j)
```

Comment: Cara ainda não uso a importação de bibliotecas no Python, mais obrigado mesmo assim.