# Somar elementos da primeira matriz com os da segunda matriz no Python

Tags: python

Existem **duas matrizes com 5 linhas e 3 colunas**, como faço para realizar a **soma dos elementos da primeira matriz com os elementos da segunda matriz**.

Por exemplo:

```
-- 1a matriz --
02 04 06 
08 10 12
14 16 18
20 22 24
26 28 30

-- 2a matriz --
01 03 05
07 09 11
13 15 17
19 21 23
25 27 29

-- Saída --
03 07 11 
15 19 23
27 31 35
39 43 47
51 55 39
```

```
Por enquanto meu código está assim, sem a parte que somas os elementos das 
linha = 0
coluna = 0

# -------- Matriz 1 --------
matrizes
mat1A = input().split()
mat1B = input().split()
mat1C = input().split()
mat1D = input().split()
mat1E = input().split() 
# -------- Matriz 2 --------
mat2A = input().split()
mat2B = input().split()
mat2C = input().split()
mat2D = input().split()
mat2E = input().split()

mat3 = [mat1A, mat1B, mat1C, mat1D, mat1E,
        mat2A,mat2B,mat2C,mat2D,mat2E]

for linha in range(len(mat3)):
    for coluna in range(len(mat3[i])):
        print (mat3[linha][coluna], end = "\t")
    print()
```

Comment: Como falei na minha resposta para a sua outra pergunta de matrizes, você pode usar `numpy`. Depois de ler as matrizes `mat1` e `mat2` como um `numpy.narray`, basta fazer `mat1 + mat2`.

Comment: Ainda não estou familiarizado com biblioteca `numpy` (nem o meu professor kkk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, crie duas constantes auxiliares para saber quantas linhas e quantas colunas terão as matrizes. (Essa etapa não é necessária, mas deixa o código mais fácil de ser compreendido)

```
LINHAS = 5
COLUNAS = 3
```

Feito isso, leia ambas as matrizes, convertendo os valores para `int` conforme [eu já lhe mostrei em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/382563/98734).

```
mat1 = []

for i in range(LINHAS):
    mat1.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])

mat2 = []

for i in range(LINHAS):
    mat2.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
```

Agora basta iterar por ambas as matrizes, somando os elementos e printando na tela.

```
for i in range(LINHAS):
    for j in range(COLUNAS):
        valor_soma = mat1[i][j] + mat2[i][j]
        print('{0:02d} '.format(valor_soma), end='')
    print()
```

Leitura adicional (é importante ler a documentação!):

- https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range
- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: me explique melhor `{0:02d}`, embora que eu saiba que faz parte do `format`

Comment: @AlexF. O primeiro `0` indica que ali vai entrar o primeiro parâmetro passado pra função `format`. O `02d` indica que o parâmetro é um integer (`d`) que deve ocupar 2 dígitos (`2`) e que o dígito à esquerda deve ser um "0" caso sobre espaço (`0`).

Comment: Entendi a sua explicação

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz dessa forma:

Créditos: Introdução a Ciência da computação Python USP/Coursera
By Fabio Kon

## Soma de matrizes

```
def cria_matriz(n_linhas, n_colunas, valor):
matriz = [] # Lista Vazia para matriz
for x in range(n_linhas):
    #Cria a linha x
    linha = [] # lista vazia para linhas
    for y in range(n_colunas):
        linha.append(valor)

    # Adiciona linha à matriz
    matriz.append(linha)
    
return matriz    

def soma_matrizes(m1, m2):
num_lin = len(m1)
num_col = len(m1[0])

num_linB = len(m2) # Verifica quantidade de linhas
num_colB= len(m2[0]) # Verifica quantidade de colunas
    
if num_lin == num_linB and num_col == num_colB:

    C = cria_matriz(num_lin, num_col, 0) # Chama A função cria_matriz

    for lin in range(num_lin): # Percorre linhas da matriz
        for col in range(num_col): # Percorre colunas da matriz
            C[lin][col] = m1[lin][col] + m2[lin][col]
    return C
else:
    return False
```